# Junit testing play framework

Tags: java, security, junit, playframework

I need to test controllers that are secured with:

`@Security.Authenticated(Secured.class).`

Even after i log in i get unauthorized,i read that i need to copy the cookie from the log in response and send it with every request to secured method. tried that without any luck.

any idea how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using `Helper.route` method for testing, logged in behavior can be accomplished by using `FakeRequest.withSession` method.

For instance, if you are using email as authentication token in your `Secured` class;

```
@Override
public String getUsername(Http.Context ctx) {
    return ctx.session().get("email");
}
```

Your test method would be like this;

```
@Test
public void testPage() {
    FakeRequest testRequest = new FakeRequest(Helpers.GET, "/page")
                               .withSession("email", "mail@example.com");
    Result result = Helpers.route(testRequest);
    assertThat(Helpers.status(result)).isEqualTo(Helpers.OK);
}
```